# How can I edit one nav/menu document and change the elements in all my blog pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know HTML and CSS but not JS yet. I am building a static blog from scratch and faced myself with a problem. When I create a post I am repeating all pages elements inside all the posts document, so, if I want to add a link to a menu, for example, I will need to edit all the files.

So, I was looking for a way to separate the menus and navs in different documents. Because if I edit them the menus will update in all de posts.

I found this method that apparently work: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp  (code below)

But, now, I don't know if this is the best method and I don't want to discover problems with it in the future, and discover that I will need to edit all the files.

This is a good method or another is better?
ps: no, I don't want a CMS.

This is the method:
Past this in head

```
<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /* Loop through a collection of all HTML elements: */
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /* Make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name: */
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /* Remove the attribute, and call this function once more: */
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /* Exit the function: */
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

and this in the body

```
    <div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 
   <script>
    includeHTML();
    </script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use PHP?

Comment: w3schools.com is not a very good source to learn JS.

Comment: @JakubMudai I never used. Do you think is better learn php?

Comment: @Dan Do you recommend another free source?

Comment: I really like codeschool.com. It's not 100% free but they have many free courses that will give you an idea if you like it.

Comment: thanks for the answers guys. But now i decided to switch to jekyll, a plataform when i can build my own site from scratch and automatize some functons with my posts and layouts. I will take a look in this site, @Dan.